# Meteor find() without login

Tags: meteor

In Meteor, how I can get all records without having to log on, only works if I login. I just want to show records with:

```
Collection.find().fetch()
```

and show all records like dashboard, but without login. Any idea?.

Comment: What does your publish function look like for that collection?

Answer (score 1):

Structure publish colllections **WITHOUT LOGIN**:

```
Meteor.publish('publication', function() {
   return Collection.find({ });
});
```

If want **CLIENT MUST LOGIN** use :

```
Meteor.publish('publication', function() {
   if(this.userId){
        return Collection.find({ });
   }
 });
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Meteor, if the develop packages like `publish` are removed, then collection data is not published by default.

To publish something, you have this code on the server:

```
 Meteor.publish('publication', function() {

   return Collection.find({ });
 });
```

You then subscribe to this publication using `Meteor.subscribe('publication')` and act on your `Collection`.

If the data in the publication is only provided to logged in users, you can always create a new publication like the one above that returns everything. You then need to subscribe to that publication, instead of the current publication you are using.

On the client, you need to subscribe to the publication using `var subscription = Meteor.subscribe("publication");`.  You can then access the collection's data after the subscription is ready using `Collection.find({})`.

Comment: I tried your example, but not works, I create  a publish function, and then put that function into suscribe, but when I call Collection.find() from "isClient", nothing happen.

Comment: Did you subscribe to the publication?

Comment: `Meteor.publish('publishOne', function(){
        var currentUserId = this.userId;
        return Collection.find({ createdBy: currentUserId });
    });
    Meteor.publish('getAll', function(){
        return Collection.find();
    });`

Comment: Please see my edited answer to see if I made it any more clear.

Comment: var suscription = Meteor.subscribe('getAll');
 console.log(suscription.ready()); //returns false

Comment: Return empty array "[ ]"

Comment: Subscriptions are not automatic, eventually `subscription.ready()` will return false. I think you might want to read about how subscriptions work: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe

Comment: @pokaxperia also see the "Subscriptions Don't Block" section of [common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes).